# Tabbed Page layout lost state when when refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, spring-mvc

We have designed the application with tabbed pages layout.

[Tabbed Page Style](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxyeiYXz3sjGQlZvTldVZG83aWc/view?usp=sharing)

the tabs are page and are created on click of menu, these are  and added in parent container  as child DOM element,it is a new form which has input elements,we could have many tabbed pages at a time. my application is in Spring MVC ,PostgresSQL ,Jquery.

What happens when refreshed, lost all the added dynamic new tabs (tabs are pages and we lost the current state).

I could share the reference code if required.

Please suggest how could I manage the state of application.

Comment: how are you loading the tabs in order on the first visit of your web site?..load the same way and in same order even after if it is refreshed..

Answer (score 0):

Window reload/refresh is a pure browser event that ends the execution of the page, you can't really have script continuity after it.

One option is to attach an alert to `window.onbeforeunload` informing the user that the content will be lost if they reload - this will work with closing the window and refreshing it.

If, however, you need to be able to reload (eg, to load fresh data in the tabs) while preserving tabs, you can use `window.onbeforeunload` to prompt the user whether they want to save the data/layout before closing, and if so, execute an AJAX call to the server, where you save the tabs (associating it with the session). This would mean that on loading the page you need to first check if there is tab data associated with the session, and load from there.

Other option - and this would be my preference - is to use `window.localStorage` to save the data on user's disk, and on page load check if there is data in `localStorage`. It has pretty wide browser support at this point, and there are good libraries that make using it a breeze. I have used [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) and can vouch for its ease and reliability.

Comment: Thanks Sidd, I am exploring your suggestions.